# How can I go back after saving using UINavigation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, save, segue

https://www.dropbox.com/s/duosl4d1fdsxehq/Storyboard.png

Here is my actual storyboard.
I am using UINavigation Controller for my app. When I press add, I open the view to add a new expense to my table. **The thing is I don't know what I should do when I press on "Save"?** I tried to put a new push segue to the previous view and it's working but after the backbutton item propose me to return to the "add new expense" view and it shouldn't do this.
How can I just reproduce the animation back button but with my save button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it was a long time ago but you should create a delegate on the second view.

```
@protocol ExpenseProtocol;

@interface NewExpenseViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<ExpenseProtocol> *delegate;
@end

@protocol ExpenseProtocol <NSObject>
- (void)didCreateNewExpense:(Expense)newExpense;
@end

@implementation NewExpenseViewController

- (void)savePressed:(id)sender {
    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate responseToSelector:@selector(didCreateNewExpense:)]) {
        [self.delegate didCreateNewExpense:_newExpense];
    }
}

@end
```

Then in your first view controller

```
@interface ListExpenseViewController () <ExpenseProtocol>
@end

@implementation ListExpenseViewController    

- (void)didCreateNewExpense:(Expense)newExpense {
    if (newExpense) {
        [_arrayExpense addObject:newExpense];
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

On the second view controller, in the method that handles the click of the save button, add:
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: That's a good start thanks.
But my tableview in the first view controller is not updated.

Comment: In the first view controller, add: - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated { [super viewWillAppear:animated]; [_tableView reloadData]; }